# Destructure an object that has the possibility of being undefined as a one-liner in a parameter list

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, undefined, object-destructuring

Given an interface `MyType`:

```
interface MyType {
  options?: { field0: string, field1: string, field2: string };
}
```

Mapping over an array, `myArray`, which has type `MyType[]`, one can destructure the `options` attribute like this:

```
myArray.map(({ options }) => {
 const { field0, field1, field2 } = options!;
```

Note the bang (`!`), because `options` could be `undefined`.

I was trying to turn this into a one-liner, like this:

```
myArray.map(({ options: { field0, field1, field2 }}) => {
```

But, this results in errors like *"Property 'field0' does not exist on type 'MyType | undefined'"* which makes sense because of the way `options` is typed.

Usually in this scenario I can add the bang operator to bypass the `undefined` check.

I tried:

```
myArray.map(({ options: { field0, field1, field2 }!}) => {
```

and:

```
myArray.map(({ options!: { field0, field1, field2 }}) => {
```

...but neither attempts are syntactically valid.

Is there a way to destructure an object that has the possibility of being `undefined` as a one-liner in a parameter list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sure that the array contains only objects with `options`, you can use a type assertion on the array itself:

```
(myArray as Required<MyType>[]).map(({ options: { field0, field1, field2 }}) => {
```

An alternative that lets you use the non-null assertion is `map`ping in two steps:

```
myArray.map(el => el.options!).map({ field0, field1, field2 }) => {
```

However, the proper safe way to handle this is to anticipate that some array elements actually might have no `options`, and default those to an empty object:

```
myArray.map(({ options: { field0, field1, field2 } = {}}) => {
```